# webbrowser control can't displaye table text left-aligned?

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I used the WebBrowser control to display multiple lines of text, but the last line of text is always centered,but I want the last line to be left-aligned as well.I set text-align:left css style on the table, but it has no effect.How do I left-align to display table text?

Comment: A few years ago people told me that System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser was fairly deprecated. It did not have the latest WebBrowsser technology, especially safety would be an issue. if you only want to use it to display HTML text, this will probably be no problem, if you can prevent people to type malicious content. Wouldn't it be better and simpler to use RichTextControl. Or consider using nuget package HtmlRenderer

Comment: A WebBrowser rendering engine renders what the HTML describes. You didn't post your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem because CSS styles are overwritten.